# Finding package requiring a specific version of another package

Tags: python, pip, sh, virtualenv, dependency-management

I have a long shell script that runs many pip installs inside a virtual env.

When installing package X, Some other, unknown package/packages are causing pip to downgrade package X to a very old version (in a loop, until it finds a compatible version).
I understood this is "backtracking" that pip does to resolve the conflict, but it doesn't give info about the reason for the backtracking.
I want to find out which package is causing that automatic downgrade, any advice how can i find that?

Comment: Have you tried pip install -verbose ?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried, but It won't show the reason for it..